# Firebase Authentication with Email Password in Angular email id is already used issue

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to connect firebase with angular application which I have successfully, the issue is when i am trying to register an user using Auth Functions of createuser using email password
The issue is when I register I first get an alert error, that is auth/email already exists (when though it doesnt) and then once i press ok it sends the successfully created user alert.

below is service code

```
import { Injectable, NgZone } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/compat/auth';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {

  UserData : any;
  constructor(private afAuth: AngularFireAuth,private router : Router, public ngZone: NgZone){
    
   }

   register(email : string, password : string) {
      return this.afAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      .then((result) => {
        window.alert('success');
        console.log(result.user)

      })
      .catch((error) => {
        window.alert(error.message);
      });
    }

    logout() {
      return this.afAuth.signOut();
    }
}
```

below is register.ts code

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthService } from 'src/app/services/auth.service';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-register',
  templateUrl: './register.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./register.component.scss']
})
export class RegisterComponent implements OnInit{
  credentials!: FormGroup;
  constructor(private router: Router, private authService: AuthService, private fb: FormBuilder)
    {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.credentials = this.fb.group({
      name: ['',[Validators.required, Validators.nullValidator]],
      email: ['',[Validators.required, Validators.email]],
      password: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(8)]],
    });

  }
  get name(){
    return this.credentials.get('name');
  }
  get email(){
    return this.credentials.get('email')
  }
  get password(){
    return this.credentials.get('password');
  }

  register(){
    this.authService.register(this.credentials.value.email, this.credentials.value.password);
  }

  routeToLogin(){
    this.router.navigate(['/login']);
  }

  routeToMain(){
    this.router.navigate(['/']);
  }

}
```

below is app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './pages/LoggedIn/home/home.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './pages/LoggedOut/login/login.component';
import { RegisterComponent } from './pages/LoggedOut/register/register.component';
import { MainComponent } from './pages/LoggedOut/main/main.component';
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';
import { AngularFireModule } from '@angular/fire/compat';
import { AngularFireAuthModule } from '@angular/fire/compat/auth';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    RegisterComponent,
    MainComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase),
    AngularFireAuthModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

I expected this to work as i saw many tutorials doing same, but i already get the error first